# What use is the Silent Princess flower?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

> This lovely flower was said to have been a favorite to the princess of Hyrule. Once feared to have gone extinct, it's recently been spotted growing in the wild.

It's an herb, but unlike other herbs, it doesn't say it its description what it does when cooked.

So what use is the Silent Princess?

Comment: Although it doesn't say in the description, the name should have made it obvious.

Comment: @JeffMercado You'd think, but it doesn't let you polymorph into princess Zelda at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it has two uses (three if you count selling it).  According to the [Zeldapedia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Silent_Princess):

> Link can **cook with it to create Sneaky Food Dishes or sell it for ten Rupees**. Like all flowers it is classified as an Herb and will usually produce herb based food dishes when cooked. It is **also used by Link as a material to upgrade certain Armor via Great Fairy**.

It appears you can cook with it like other herbs to create a Sneaky food dish, and also use it as a material to upgrade armor through the Great Fairy.

Answer (score 3):

The Silent Princess is a flower that can be cooked with to create food that will increase your stealth.

It is also significant in the story, too, as it has a whole memory devoted to it.
In the after-credits end scene, the Silent Princess can be seen blooming (in the picture down below). In the memory, Zelda stated that the flower was on the verge of extinction. This is symbolic of Hyrule and how it will flourish after Link defeated Calamity Ganon.
[image: Twilight princess in the final cutscene]

Comment: Mental typo: "Twilight Princess"?

Answer (score 0):

The Silent Princess, when cooked, simply helps you become silent. Well, not exactly silent, but quieter.
...So enemies and horses can't hear you very well.